# Why is hookes law not obeyed in vertical circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, string

We know that $$T=-kx=-k(R-L)$$where $L$ is the natural length of string, so the tension force must be constant. but in vertical circular motion the tension force is not constant (via analysis of centripetal force). How can I reconcile these two ideas if tension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to reconcile.  One simply needs to take the next step, and see that the length of the string varies with time.  This can be very obvious if you replace the string with a slinky.

Comment: How come in some questions I’ve worked on the radius of vertical circular motion is constant?

Comment: @Richie, that depends on the problem.   If the vertical circle is constrained by an inextensible string or a fixed ramp, that would be different than one constrained by an extensible string.

Comment: @Richie In addition to what BowlOfRed said, we often simplify the physics in problems.  In reality, strings have a very high k, so they don't stretch much.  Steel wires have even higher.